# Equivalence of with and without replacement sampling

Tags: references, experiment-design, mathematical-statistics, probability

After some heavy reordering and canceling of factorials, I discovered that the following experiment is approximately equivalent for $m \ll n < N$ if conducted with or without replacement:

> In $n$ turns, draw marbles (with/without replacement) from an urn containing $m$ white and $N-m$ black marbles. Count the white marbles.

Now, the "with replacement" part is a Bernoulli trial:

> Throw $m$ times an unfair coin with success probability $n/N$. Count the number of successes.

Are there any pitfalls in this approximation?

I am pretty sure that this is textbook knowledge. Can you recommend a good book where this approximation is derived?

I did the exercise in order to [Derive househould weights from a uniformly distributed person sample](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26060/6432).

Comment: Your first example us the hypergeometric distribution, while the second one is the binomial distribution. This approximation is quite common and works well for large N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially answered in comments:

Your first example us the hypergeometric distribution, while the second one is the binomial distribution. This approximation is quite common and works well for large N. – MånsT   See also  [Binomial Approximation to Hypergeometric Probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360127/binomial-approximation-to-hypergeometric-probability)